# How to change QGraphicsView background

Tags: c++, qt, background, qgraphicsview

How can I change `QGraphicsView` background like this image.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the image (which has lines but could have a lion), or to have lines drawn in the background as a grid similar to your attached image? If it is the earlier, [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/6313/qgraphicsview-with-qpixmap-background) might help. If it is the later, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981512/draw-a-line-with-qpainter-using-qgraphicsview-subclass) can help.

Comment: @apalomer I need second one, lines drawn in the background as a grid similar to this image